# Using stance and skill trick together

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Can you use the stance dancing spider with the skill trick wall jumper? Trick states you must make a successful climb check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing would prevent you from using these two things together, however, it would be up to your DM if the martial stance waives the climb check to benefit from the skill trick. But even if you have to make a skill check, it shouldn't be hard to make. Having a climb speed allows you to take a 10, afterall.

**[Dance of the Spider](http://therafimrpg.wikidot.com/dance-of-the-spider) states:**

> While you are in this stance, you gain a benefit similar to the [spider climb](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spiderClimb.htm) spell. You gain a climb speed of 20 feet. You do not need to make a [Climb](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/climb.htm) check to traverse a vertical or horizontal surface, even if you attempt to move across a ceiling. You cannot take a [run](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/movement.htm#runx4) action while climbing in this manner.

**[Wall Jumper](http://marksworld.zeemer.com/files/skilltricks.html#3) states:**

> If you have succeeded on a climb check to ascend or descend a wall during this or your previous turn, you can leap horizontally from that wall as if you had a running start.

**Me Personally as DM:**

I would waive the climb check. You act as if you have spider climb and even have a climb speed. It isn't game breaking at all, and can only be done once per encounter anyway.

Comment: The 3.5 version of [Spider Climb](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spiderClimb.htm) suggests 'the subject gains a climb speed of 20 feet'.

Comment: @KRyan Actually, both do. See [Kazagha's link to d20srd](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spiderClimb.htm), and for *dance of the spider*: "While you are in this stance, you gain a benefit similar to the spider climb spell (PH 283). You gain a climb speed of 20 feet. You do not need to make a Climb check to traverse a vertical or horizontal surface, even if you attempt to move across a ceiling." [ToB p.76]